# When will MySQL utf8mb4 support be mandatory?

Tags: mysql

With recent upgrade, CiviCRM showed me this message

> Future versions of CiviCRM may require MySQL utf8mb4 support. It is
>   recommended, though not yet required, to configure your MySQL server
>   for utf8mb4 support. You will need the following MySQL server
>   configuration: innodb_large_prefix=true innodb_file_format=barracuda
>   innodb_file_per_table=true

Since I am on shared hosting plan, it is likely that the host will not update these global MySQL settings. I guess that can mean for me the end of updates or a very tedious task of migrating CiviCRM elsewhere.

Is there any information when these MySQL changes will become mandatory?

Comment: Linked question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/37806/35

Answer (score 7):

It seems like it's still under discussion as of last week. See e.g. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/979