# How to use full unicode on custom fields

Tags: custom-fields

There's an API call `System.utf8conversion` which will change all your tables to MySQL/MariaDB's utf8mb4 format, i.e. full unicode with emoji support, rather than the incomplete utf8 implementation of old.

I ran this and it worked fine but then found that when I add a custom fieldset, that table is set to the old UTF8 charset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incomplete UTF8 support is [hard coded](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/5.30/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomField.php#L1619) into the core code before 5.33 (*thanks @michaelmcandrew!*).

The solution seems to be to re-run the `System.utf8conversion` routine

- Pre 5.33: do this after any time you create a field/fieldset (including anytime you install an extension that creates a custom field/fielset)
- 5.33+ do this once, then the only time it should be needed again is if an extension hard-codes the old UTF8 in place.

Note that you can use the [uh-oh](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/uhoh) extension to help discover whether your db uses the old UTF8 stuff.

Comment: Note that there is a [PR 18642](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18642) to fix this, thanks Seamus!

Comment: That PR is merged, but not in 5.31 so assume it will make it to 5.32

Comment: Actually it looks like it came out in 5.33 (https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/civicrm-533-release)